# Working with django and sklearn enormous models

Tags: django, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm working on a django project that uses sklearn SVR models. The training part takes a lot of time and I need to use it relatively fast, so I'm trying to do the training part offline and store it in db / filesystem, and then the online just load it and use the models.

Problem is, when I try to use cPickle to serialize the data, I end up with over 500MB at best (and sometimes couple of GBs at worse). I can't load so much data online fast enough, it will make requests very slow.

So my question is, whats the recommended way to use sklearn SVR with django, when I want high performance? Should I use cPickle to serialize / deserialize or something else? Should I zip it? And what about loading, obviously I can't load this whole data per request, so is the way to go is putting it in cache?

Thanks,

Comment: I believe the SVR model needs to be (saved to disk and) loaded once, preferably globally, when instantiating the server - before the server is available for requests. After that, any request that needs prediction, should be able to access the globally available model, and since prediction is instant, it shouldn't be a problem. At least that's how I would think about this in cases where I need to do something similar. Would the model change frequently?

Comment: It doesnt make sense to do that unless your data is already in the django server. There is no way to achieving realtime with SVR and GB of menory transfer through web.

Comment: @mkaran will it work properly with caching systems like redis? I don't want to fill my server's RAM with the models.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Imanoi Luengo I'm not sure you understood me, its all on the same server there's no transfer between servers. when I run it offline I run it offline on the same django server, I'm just not sure as to how to serialize / deserialize the data, as its too big. Thanks!

Comment: Way too broad, way too incomplete. Redis is not necessarily a caching-system and it's memory-based; so using it to not flood memory sounds well... conflicting. Try to explain a bit more what you really want. There are probably only two approaches possible: keep your learned SVR model in memory and use it; OR load and use on demand from some serialization (sklearn-based serialization vs. customized-one). You should ask yourself too, why your models are that big. That seems a bit big for sparse-data (which is usually the case for well-trained SVMs).And why cPickle?sklearn brings something tuned!

Comment: @sascha Yeah I meant Amazon ElastiCache Redis Cluster, which uses its own external memory and don't flood the instance. I though I mentioned I'm on AWS now I see I didn't. ""You should ask yourself too, why your models are that big. That seems a bit big for sparse-data"" - that is actually helpful because I wasn't sure if it was norm or too big. I train data for a lot of items and categories (store catalog) so maybe there's too much input. Does sklearn way (you talk about joblib right?) faster / less data then cPickle?

Comment: @RonenNess I believe joblib has better compression. As for external caching, e.g. Redis, I recently saw a webinar regarding Spark models being served by Redis ML - which currently supports only trees. It might work for your case? I am not sure if it is tied to Spark...Take a look at [this](https://redislabs.com/modules/machine-learning/). In general though, try to reduce the size of your models as sascha suggested - sparce matrices, maybe something like PCA for dimensionality reduction etc.